# String view of file array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of files in Javascript. How can I create a string with their names and sizes?
Example:

`[ {File1} {File2} ] => "File: my_file1 size: size1 bytes, "File: my_file2 size: size2 bytes"`.

Not using for - I want to use functions :)
If use for it could be something like this

```
function createStringForFileArray(arr){
        let result = "";
        for (let i = 0; i <arr.length; i++ ){
            result+= "File"+arr[i].name+" size "+arr[i].size+" ";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why specifically do you not want to use a for loop?

Comment: What's wrong with using `for` ?

Comment: I don't know. I think it's more compact

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but you can optimize for loops by storing the "to" value in a variable as such: `for (let i=0, j=arr.length; i<j; i++){//do stuff};`.  This greatly improves the speed of for loops.

Comment: I updated my answer to just use `reduce` without `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `map` with `reduce`:

```
let str = files
    .map(f => "File: " + f.name + " size: " + f.size)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + ", " + curr);
```

**Edit:** You can do it with just `reduce`. The original solution by @chsdk did this and was posted before mine, but it had an error (now corrected). So you may want to accept that answer instead.

```
let str = files.reduce((prev, curr, index, arr) => {
    return prev + "File: " + curr.name + " size: " + curr.size + (index === arr.length - 1 ? "" : ", ");
}, "");
```

Comment: I think the answer from @chsdk might be better actually, since it seems to use only one loop.

Comment: Thank you @FrankModica for such a fair play ;)

Comment: @FrankModica Thank you for pointing out the problem with reduce in my answer.

Comment: And for your answer, in the first solution `.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + ", " + curr)` can just be replaced with `join(", ")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to return a unique string from all your array elements.

Your code would be like this:

```
function createStringForFileArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b, i){
    return a + "File: " + b.name + " size: " + b.size + (i !== array.length - 1 ? ", " : "");
}, "");
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
var array = [{
    name: "file1",
    size: "500Mb"
  },
  {
    name: "Test",
    size: "0Kb"
  }, {
    name: "TAnother File",
    size: "30Kb"
  }
];

function createStringForFileArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b, i){
    return a + "File: " + b.name + " size: " + b.size + (i !== array.length - 1 ? ", " : "");
}, "");
}

console.log(createStringForFileArray(array));
```

Or you can use `.map()` function like this:

```
function createStringForFileArray(arr) {
  return array.map(function(f) {
    return "File: " + f.name + " size:" + f.size;
  }).join(", ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate using `Array#map` and create a string for each file, then join all the strings:

```js
const files = [{ name: 'file1', size: 1111 }, { name: 'file2', size: 2222 }];

const result = files.map(({ name, size }) => `File: ${name} size: ${size} bytes`).join(', ');

console.log(result);
```